# How can I fix this state error when I create a log storage in local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good morning, I get a syntax error and I don't know what the problem is in the state part

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        name = '',
        email = '',
        password = ''
    }
}



<form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit } >
                <input type='name' placeholder='Nombre' value={ this.state.name } onChange={ this.onChangeName } required />
                <input type='email' placeholder='Email' value={ this.state.email } onChange={ this.onChangeEmail } required />
                <input type='password' placeholder='Contraseña' value={ this.state.password } onChange={ this.onChangePassword } required />
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmUNU.png)

Comment: use semi column instead of equal (e.g. name: "fanjiloo")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are defining an object, you have to use a colon instead of the equals:

```
  this.state = {
    name : '',
    email : '',
    password : ''
  }
```

Comment: @fanjiooJr when assigning something to a variable you have to use the equals - but inside the object when assigning something to the properties of an object, you have to use the colon - just like in my example - you can try that super quick, just by copying the code into the console of the browser